# Maven blocking on downloading jars (artifactId :tomcat-maven-plugin)

Tags: maven, maven-tomcat-plugin

i have a problem with tomcat-maven-plugin : 
here's the code

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-beta-1</version>
</plugin>
```

so after running this command: `clean tomcat:run`

i get this result :

```
 [INFO] Scanning for projects...
 [INFO]                                                                          
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [INFO] Building seleniumproject Maven Webapp 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [INFO] 
 [INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ seleniumproject ---
 [INFO] Deleting C:\Users\Amira\junoWorkspace\seleniumproject\target
 [INFO] 
 [INFO] >>> tomcat-maven-plugin:1.0-beta-1:run (default-cli) @ seleniumproject >>>
 [INFO] 
 [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources)  @seleniumproject ---
 [debug] execute contextualize
 [WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
 [INFO] Copying 0 resource
 [INFO] 
 [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @  seleniumproject ---
 [INFO] No sources to compile
 [INFO] 
 [INFO] <<< tomcat-maven-plugin:1.0-beta-1:run (default-cli) @ seleniumproject <<<
 [INFO] 
 [INFO] --- tomcat-maven-plugin:1.0-beta-1:run (default-cli) @ seleniumproject ---


 Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-plugin-  api/2.0/maven-plugin-api-2.0.pom
 Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-plugin-api/2.0/maven-plugin-api-2.0.pom (601 B at 1.2 KB/sec)
 Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/junit/junit/3.8.2/junit-3.8.2.pom
 .......................................
 Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/tomcat/dbcp/6.0.16/dbcp-6.0.16.jar (194 KB at 128.6 KB/sec)

 Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/tomcat/coyote/6.0.16/coyote-6.0.16.jar (725 KB at 367.5 KB/sec)
```

As you see it blocks on downloading : 
Is there a solution please

Comment: What do you mean by `blocks on downloading`?  Maybe there is a network issue.  Can you try again?

Comment: i'm connecting to internet , but it stopps on downloading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where you get the url from:

```
http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/
```

but it looks you have changed the configuration in the settings.xml file, cause Maven Central has http://repo1.maven.apache.org/maven2/ instead. Furthermore i can recommend to use a repository manager (Nexus, Archiva, Artifactory).

BTW: Why are you using the mojo.codehaus tomcat plugin and not the offical of Apache http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin.html

Comment: `repo.maven.apache.org` is a synonym for `repo1.maven.org`.

Comment: I know but it's indicating a change in the settings.xml or a pom file.